# Can I connect a Samsung Galaxy A9 by an ethernet cable (no wifi)?

Tags: samsung, usb

Has any other member been able to do this? I believe that you go to Settings - Developer Options - USB/Internet/Ethernet. If this last option is not there then it will not connect. I must confirm this before I purchase the phone as I need to open the box to check. Thanks.

Comment: You can't connect your device to an Ethernet cable, but using the function "USB tethering" there is the possibility to get network access via USB and a connected PC: https://screentimelabs.com/help/connect-to-the-internet-through-usb/

Comment: No. you can't connect an ethernet cable to phone directly. It is possible if you connect with cable(USB type C to Ethernet receiver) OR USB Type C OTG(USB port to Ethernet receiver). Example shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uisnj8Xufp0